# Error with R Script - Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404. Called from: open.connection(x, "rb")

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am working on this code, but for some reason I keep ending up with a 404 error even though the website works. Not sure where I made a mistake but would appreciate any community advice. I believe I made a mistake somewhere in the link to the website, but I'm not sure what to put in, I tried the  bare minimum "http://www.ufcstats.com/", as well as the '/fighter-details/'.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

link = "http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all"
page = read_html(link)

name = page %>% html_nodes(".b-link_style_black") %>% html_text()
name_links = page %>% html_nodes(".b-link_style_black") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("http://www.ufcstats.com/fighter-details/", ., sep="") %>% trimws()

get_Info = function(name_link) {
  fighter_page = read_html(name_link)
  tibble(
    name = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-content__title-highlight") %>% html_text(),
    record = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-content__title-record") %>% html_text(),
    height = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box_style_small-width .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text(),
    weight = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box_style_small-width .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text(),
    reach = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box_style_small-width .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text(),
    stance = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box_style_small-width .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text(),
    dob = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box_style_small-width .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(5)") %>% html_text(),
    sig_strikes_per_min= fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box-left .b-list__info-box-left .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text(),
    sig_striking_accuracy = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box-left .b-list__info-box-left .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text(),
    sig_strikes_abs_per_min = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box-left .b-list__info-box-left .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text(),
    sig_strike_def = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box-left .b-list__info-box-left .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text(),
    avg_takedown = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box_style-margin-right .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text(),
    takedown_accuracy = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box_style-margin-right .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text(),
    takedown_defense = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__info-box_style-margin-right .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text(),
    sub_avg = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-list__box-list_margin-top .b-list__box-list-item_type_block:nth-child(5)") %>% html_text(),
    last_fight = fighter_page %>% html_nodes(".b-statistics__table-row+ .js-fight-details-click .b-fight-details__table-col~ .b-fight-details__table-col+ .l-page_align_left .b-fight-details__table-text+ .b-fight-details__table-text") %>% html_text()
  ) -> t
  return(t)
}

df <- map_dfr(name_links, get_Info)
```

Here are the error codes I receive:

```
Browse[1]> Q
> library(rvest)
Warning message:
In for (i in seq_along(a)) if (all(nam[i] != std.attr)) { :
  closing unused connection 6 (http://www.ufcstats.com/fighter-details/http://www.ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9)

...

> df <- map_dfr(name_links, get_Info)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
Called from: open.connection(x, "rb")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url returned after `html_attr("href")` is the complete url so you don't need to add another `paste` there. Try with the following -

```
library(rvest)

name_links <- page %>% html_nodes(".b-link_style_black") %>% html_attr("href")

df <- purrr::map_dfr(name_links, get_Info)
```